# Point Grey Bumblebee2 firewire 1394 with Nvidia Jetson TK1 board

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I have successfully interfaced [Point Grey Bumblebee2](http://www.ptgrey.com/bumblebee2-stereo-vision-08-mp-color-firewire-1394a-25mm-sony-icx204-camera) firewire1394 camera with Nvida Jetson TK1 board and I get the video using [Coriander](http://damien.douxchamps.net/ieee1394/coriander/) and video for Linux loop back device is working as well. But when I tried to access camera using OpenCV and Coriander at the same time, I have conflicts. And when I tried to access the video from camera by closing the Coriander then I can get the video but in that case I am not able to change the mode and format of the video. Anyone can help me to resolve this problem. Can I change the video mode of the camera from OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to install the flycapture sdk for ARM if you want to do it manually (by code). The flycap UI software i dont believe works on ARM, let alone ubuntu 14.04, just ubuntu 12.04 x86. If you have access, what I usually do is plug it into my windows machine and use the Flycap software to change the configurations on the camera.

I found this question completely randomly, but coincidentally I am trying to interface the bumblebee2 with the jetson right now as well. Would you care to share as to what firewire mini-PCIe you used and how you went about any configurations (stock or grinch kernel, which L4T version) ?

Also, although not fully complete, you can view a code example as to how to interface with the camera using the flycaputre sdk here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver. It is a ROS driver, but you can just reference the [PointGreyCamera.cpp](https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/blob/master/pointgrey_camera_driver/src/PointGreyCamera.cpp) file for examples if your not using ROS.

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try out your method tomorrow and regarding question I did made guideline to install firewire 1394 driver along with video for Linux module. Can you share your email address.

Comment: I dont want to post it here, so just view on my github account https://github.com/l0g1x

Comment: I am using Mini PCI Express firewire card from StarTech.

Answer (score 0):

This is not well advertised, but PtGrey [do not support firewire on ARM](http://ptgrey.com/support/downloads/10367) (page 4):

> Before installing FlyCapture, you must have the following prerequisites:... A Point Grey USB 3.0 camera, (Blackfly, Grasshopper3, or Flea3)
>   **Other Point Grey imaging cameras (FireWire, GigE, or CameraLink) are NOT supported**

However as you have seen it is possible to use the camera (e.g. in Coriander) using standard firewire tools.

libdc1394 or [the videography library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videography) should do what you need.